# I am trying to increment count value in DB when the user click on article using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to increment count value in db but **$request->session()->exists($articledetails->id)** this condition is not working,please guide how can i store id in session ? please help me thanks.

```
   public function articledetails(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $articledetails = ArticleLibrary::with('articleCategory')->where('id', $id)->first();

        if (!$articledetails) {
            abort(404);
        }



       if ($request->session()->exists($articledetails->id)) {

            $articledetails->increment('article_view');
        }
        $data = [

            'articledetails' => $articledetails
        ];

        return view('articles-details', $data);
    }
```

Comment: why are you expecting there to be a variable in the session named with that id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this code hope that it will help you thanks.

```
  if (!$request->session()->exists('articleDetial' . $articledetails->id)) {
                $request->session()->put('articleDetial' . $articledetails->id, true);
                $articledetails->increment('article_view');
            }
```